# Not able to retrieve button text JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to retrieve the text of a button that is clicked. I've read up on other suggestions for similar questions, but cant seem to get it to work. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z3PKm/63/
Which currently isn't working. What am I doing wrong, or what should I do which is right?
Thanks!
I've tried to copy the following solution

```
alert($(this).attr("value"));
```

But it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: thanks for creating a fiddle with your question by the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:-

`.text()` will give you the text of the `button` as per your example. You are using `button` and not `input type="button"` If it was `input type="button"` then `.val()` would work.

```
function test(name) {
    alert($(name).text());
}
```

Since you are using jquery you can use the click event

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z3PKm/90/ what am i doing wrong? click the button, it doesn't return the text.

Comment: You are not calling text() method.. instead you are calling .text which will out put the contents of the .text `function` not invoking it.. Try this function test(name) {
    alert($(name).text());
}

Answer (score 3):

The type of button that you are using are not using `value`, they are text.

Write this:

```
$(name).text()
```

Comment: I didn't realize the different buttons had different fields! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it **[jQuery style.](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/PMcaS/)**

This also show you how to use inputs and buttons and `text()` or `val()` as appropriate

```
$('.choose').on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    alert('text: '+$this.text()+'\nval: '+$this.val()); 
}); // end on click
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `alert($(name).text());` I have updated the jsfiddle with the same:
    [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3PKm/86%22)